# Why are topic subscribers on the ActiveMQ admin UI constantly changing?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

I have a JMS non-durable topic with multiple subscribers (using ActiveMQ).

Each subscriber is a web application deployed on a separate Tomcat instance.
When a message arrives, I want it delivered to all subscribers (somewhat of a distributed cache implementation).

I've noticed that not always the message gets delivered to all subscribers. When looking at the ActiveMQ admin UI I see the **list of topic subscribers (as well as the list of connections) constantly changing**. E.g. I see 17 subscribers, I refresh the ActiveMQ admin UI, then I see 19 subscribers, I refresh again - I see 18 etc.

What's wrong? I know that all the tomcats are up all the time. My understanding of JMS topics is that if the application is up, the message should always get delivered. Have I misunderstood something? I see no logical reason for this subscriber 'flashing'.

P.S. I'd rather not try durable topics - I don't need the message delivered if the application is not up.

Comment: I'd suspect your application is either reconnecting or constantly timing out and creating new sessions (or both).  Can you post your subscriber logic?

Comment: The subscriber logic would be really helpful. Also, you can try writing an ActiveMQ plugin (it's a matter of extending a provided ActiveMQ class and then registering it in the config). The plugin will allow you to see subscriptions and unsubscriptions.